# showing me php session available in webpage,even after not being available

Tags: php, mysql, session

problem

1. after I'm logged in,my session does exist.that fine(but keeps remaining for login page,even after closing the browser).but after logged in when I go to the next page,session doesn't exist for that page.
   problem
2. not inserting any items in the table,because no session exists on second page.
   please look at the code for clear understanding.

Here is admin_login.php

```
     <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
    echo "hello boss,go to<a href='inventory_list.php'>inventory Page</a>";
   }
    else{


if(isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["pass"])) {
$manager=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_POST["user"]);
$pass=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#','',$_POST["pass"]);
}
require_once "connect_to_db.php";
$sqlcommand='SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username="$manager" AND password="$pass" LIMIT 1';
$query=mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sqlcommand);
$numrow=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrow==0){
header("location:admin_login.php");
}

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$id=$row['id'];
$manager=$row['username'];
$pass=$row['password'];

$_SESSION['manager']=$manager;
$_SESSION['password']=$pass;
$_SESSION["id"]=$id;
echo "go to <a href='inventory_list.php'>inventory page</a>";
exit();
}

session_destroy();


    ?>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>admin login page</title>

 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="formfield" name="formfield" method="post" action="admin_login.php" >
 User Name:
 </br><input type="text" name="user" id="user" />
 </br>
 Password:
 </br>
 <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
 </br>
 <input type="submit" id="subm" value="login" />
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

here is the code for inventory_list.php

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
  $id=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["id"]);
  $manager=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["manager"]);
  $password=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);
  include "connect_to_db.php";
  $sqlcommand="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM admin WHERE id='$id' AND username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
  $counting=mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sqlcommand);
  $numrow=mysqli_num_rows($counting);
  if($numrow==0){
  echo "you better get out of here";
  exit();
  }




 if(isset($_POST["product_name"])){


    $productname=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z]#i','',$_POST["product_name"]);
    $productprice=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_POST["product_price"]);
    $productdetails=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_POST["product_detail"]);
    $productdivision=$_POST["product_division"];
    $productsubdivision=$_POST["product_subdivision"];
    include "connect_to_db.php";
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE product_name='$productname' ";
    $counting=mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sql) ;
    $numrow=mysqli_num_rows($counting);
    if($numrow>0){
    echo "you have added the product before";
    print_r($numrow);

    }



    $sql="INSERT INTO products (product_name,price,details,category,subcategory,date_added) VALUES ($productname,$productprice,$productdetails,$productdivision,$productsubdivision,now())";
    mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sql) ;
    $pid=mysqli_insert_id();
    $newfile=$pid.jpg;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"$productsubdivision/$newfile");
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
       }
    }
     else{
     echo "hello Killer";
     echo "go to <a href='admin_login.php'>login page</a>";
     exit();
     }  

     session_destroy();     
     ?>
     <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>

     <fieldset>
     <legend value="fucking add something">Add product,dude</legend>
     <form id="formo" action="inventory_list.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Product Name:<input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" placeholder="Type Product Name" /></br>
      Product price:<input type="text"  name="product_price" id="product_price" placeholder="Type Product price" /></br>
      Product division:
        <select id="product_division" name="product_division">
         <option>select</option>
         <option value="food">food</option>
       <option value="apparel">apparel</option>
       <option value="beauty">beauty</option>
       <option value="toys">toys</option>
        </select>
       </br>    
      Product type:
         <select id="product_subdivision" name="product_subdivision" >
          <option value="">select</option>
            <option value="Rice">Rice</option>
          <option value="milk">milk</option>
          <option value="Meat">Meat</option>
          <option value="sweet">sweet</option>
          <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
          <option value="cap">cap</option>
          <option value="shirt">shirt</option>
          <option value="pant">pant</option>
          </select>
        </br>
     Product Detail:<textarea id="product_detail" name="product_detail" placeholder="Type Product Name" ></textarea> 
      </br>
      product Image:<input type="file" id="image" name="image" value="upload Product pic" />
     </br>
     <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add This Item Now" />

   </form>
   </fieldset>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to put `session_start()` at the top of each script. You seem to have missed it on `admin_login.php`.

Comment: @user2943607
is your problem solved or not

Comment: @MikeW not working,yet.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution One possible solution may be enable your browser cookies. If cookies are disabled then **$_SESSION["manager"]** will not be available there.

Comment: But for creating session we have to start session with the help of **session_start()**

Comment: For sessions, a random id is generated on each page which is stored in cookies. To get that session id from cookies, browser cookie must be enabled.

Comment: Just add session_start(); in starting and remove the line  session_destroy();  in admin_login.php. This should work as in mine. Enjoy..

Comment: does that work for you?is it inserting items on the table too?please let me know,because it's not working for me even after follow your suggestion.thanks for your time

Comment: I didn't insert in database. but session is available on 2nd page. And definitely your records will be updated with in **IF Condition**

Answer (score 1):

Add below line at top of page  :

```
<?php
session_start() // Add this line 
if(isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
```

And remove session_destroy from 1st page. It will works. cool...

Answer (score 0):

Please add start session below line in admin page

```
<?php
 session_start() // Add this line in your code. it will work fine. 
if(isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
echo "hello boss,go to<a href='inventory_list.php'>inventory Page</a>";
```

If this answer solve your problem then please mark it as an answer so that others can use it in future

Comment: it's not still working.whatever,I'll keep trying by myself.anyway,Thank you so much for your time,bro.